# Microsoft Edge adds parameters after navigating to a route on angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, microsoft-edge

I have a form being filled in two steps, the first form fills in the main part of an object and the second, the sub-part. There is a method that navigates back from form2 to form1 that works on Chrome and Firefox, but with Microsoft Edge it seems to add "/?object", and it's something that I'm not doing in code.

my button to go back from form2 to form1

```
<button class="btn btn-default pull-right" (click)="onCancel()">{{ 'button.back' | translate }}</button>
```

my method onCancel()

```
onCancel() {
    this.goal.target = this.target;
    this.service.setGoalToSave(this.goal);
    if (this.isEditing) {
       this.router.navigate(['goals/goalForm', this.goal.goalId.toString()]);
    } else {
       this.router.navigate(['goals/goalForm']);
    }
}
```

Microsoft Edge navigates to

> http://localhost:8080/my-service/?target01=&target02=&target03=&target04=&target05=&target06=&target07=&target08=&target09=&target10=&target11=&target12=&annualTarget=

But that isn't a valid route, so it redirects to my main page.

Anyone knows what is causing this or how can I fix it?

Comment: If you try `this.router.navigate(['goals/goalForm', this.goal.goalId]` instead, it will work in similar way :)

Comment: goalId is only a number, not an object and it's used only when editing an existing object, if it's creating, no id should be passed, and if you look at the resulting URL, it doesn't have the "goals/goalForm" prefix

Comment: can you post a reproduction

Comment: I have the same problem, only in Microsoft Edge.

Comment: I had this same problem too, was really irritating that IE11 behaved differently than IE Edge.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To fix this problem, add type="button" to the button tag. Edge is apparently assuming that any button without an explicit type is type="submit", for which it is posting the values in the form.

I had explicitly included the form tag in my page so that I could access the form properties in the .ts code. I removed that form tag and associated code, and the navigation works in Edge. So Edge seems to be assuming that my button was a submit button. After including type="button" in the button attributes, I was able to put the form tag back in, and it all still worked.

Comment: I'll check this, although I can see it makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: I fixed this by doing `<form onSubmit="return false"...`