# Microsoft edge adds a parameter to URL that is not expected

Tags: html, angular, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

Not expected parametr ?zx=djlj8eui511x adding to url after clicking

```
<a [href]="navItem.url" *ngIf="navItem.index <= wizardConfiguration.activeTab.index"
                       class="rktn-wizard-navigation-container_passed-item"
                       [ngClass]="{'_active': navItem.index === wizardConfiguration.activeTab.index}">
                        {{getMessage(navItem.key)}}
                    </a>
```

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45626973/microsoft-edge-adds-parameters-after-navigating-to-a-route-on-angular-2).

Answer (score 0):

Try to refer the following code to set the href attribute:

```
<div *ngFor="let option of navItem">
<a href="{{option.url}}?index={{option.index}}" 
class="rktn-wizard-navigation-container_passed-item">
  {{option.key}}
</a>
</div>
```

Besides, You could also rebuild the url property (add the parameter to the url property) in the component.ts file, then bind the value to the link.