# Edge add parameter to URL that is not espected

Tags: url, frontend, microsoft-edge, url-parameters, liferay-7

I got this problem that only happens on Microsoft EDGE, I have a page that generate an menu like this:

```
                    <a href="${homeList.getLink()}" referrerpolicy="origin"></a> 
                    <script>console.log('${homeList.getLink()}');</script>
                        <div class="az-portlet-home-card-img-container">
                            <img class="az-portlet-home-card-img"  src="${homeList.getImage()}" >
                            <div class="az-portlet-home-card-text  text-center">
                                     <div class="az-portlet-home-card-innerText">
                                            ${homeList.getText()}
                                     </div>
                              </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="az-portlet-home-card-plus-incon" >
                            <img src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/images/corner_icon.png">
                            <span class="az-portlet-home-plus-sign">+</span>
                        </div>
                </div>
```

The href of  works fine in all browsers except EDGE because he adds someting like

?zx=vioeDFwfjha

for example, in chrome I got the linK:
http://localhost:1234/web/acores/turismo

In EDGE I got the link:
http://localhost:1234/web/acores?zx=bhjfeuRdf/turismo

What's this and How I get read of it?

Comment: How do you get the link value? Could you please provide [a minimal sample to reproduce the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? I tested with your code but it can't reproduce the issue, the result is like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/yuzhou0602/93Ly7o8r/1/). I also find a [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45626973/microsoft-edge-adds-parameters-after-navigating-to-a-route-on-angular-2) which may be helpful to your issue. You could also check if there's some "submit" action which leads to this issue.

Comment: This is made in LifeRay (MVC), I got java classes that passes the values to JSP, logging the values it's all ok, but when Old EDGE render the page generate this.

Only happens on Old EDGE, with the new one it's ok and with all other browsers and mobile is fine to.

O notice that every time I access the page via a link (like a menu or other link) this parameter is added, but if I am in the page and make a refresh works fine... It's like a route that is injected in the URL... very strange.. I will try to make a video to show.

Comment: Here is a link to a demo video that I made. Note that the adress is changed on render mode.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Xwjsz8Lk8pbgNReax0FPe_c14nuwyGGa/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I'm afraid we can't locate the issue through the video. Please check the generated link in the code and compare it with the link after clicking. Check if there's any difference between them. Besides, the site configuration in IIS or any other server you using may cause the issue. Here I just use IIS as an example: if you use [url rewrite](https://support.secureauth.com/hc/en-us/articles/360019890071-IIS-URL-Rewrite-Browser-based-redirection) setting in IIS, it will make redirect in some specific browser. You could also check if you used some configuration like this.

Comment: Seconding the first comment: You really need to provide a [mcve]: Edit your question and  provide detailed steps to reproduce. Include the Liferay version and the simplest possible code for a portlet that enables anyone to reproduce the issue.